# Filtering a table with multiple where criteria

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, filtering, where-clause

I am trying to select from a table only pulling data that fit my criteria.
I basically want to

> exclude year 2019, 
>  exclude where acres = 0,
>    exclude where
>   policynumber is null,
>   exclude where (liab = 0 and acres>0).

I may be getting the negation of some of these wrong as I'm not getting the expected number of rows.Is there a way to do this in a series of steps as I would in excel, but I obviously don't want to do it in excel.

```
from  [dbo].[Hail_Data_2013_2018_incl_SSN]
where cropyear <> 2019 or (policynumber is not null) or (PolicyAcres <> 0) 
or (Policyliability <> 0 or PolicyAcres < 0)
```

Doing this step by step would work, is there someway this can be rewritten to do it in steps or are my combination of 'or' wrong?

Comment: I think you may want "AND" instead of "OR"?

Comment: Tag with your DBMS. [ask] [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic needs some work. I suspect you need "AND" rather than "OR". Post a data table and the expected results and we can help you chase this down.

```
declare @mydata as table (policyacres int, policynumber varchar(10), Policyliability int, cropyear int)

INSERT INTO @mydata
Select -1, '123x', 0, 2019 UNION ALL
Select 1,'224y', 0, 2019 UNION ALL
Select -1,'223d',0,2020

Select * from @mydata 
 where cropyear <> 2019 and (policynumber is not null) and (PolicyAcres <> 0) and (Policyliability = 0 and PolicyAcres < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
where 
  (cropyear <> 2019) and
  (policynumber is not null) and 
  (PolicyAcres <> 0) and 
  (Policyliability <> 0 or PolicyAcres <= 0)
```